# VS Code - can I disable the 'No Python interpreter' warning?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-python

I use VS Code for multiple languages and don't always need an interpreter. I also use multiple Python versions, usually managed via Pipenv. I find the constant nagging to select an interpreter really annoying; can I disable it?
After all, I'll soon quickly find out I don't have one selected when I try and run the code.

Comment: change the `pythonpath` setting in the Global/User settings, that will be the default for all your workspaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can go into settings, extensions, Python ( which is generating the popup) , and there you can check the box next to "Python: Disable Installation Check"

Is you open the settings.json file instead, you are going to add/check the setting to this.

```
"python.disableInstallationCheck": true
```

For reference, I'm on VS Code for Mac v1.6, Python extension is v2021.12.1559732655.